# ¿Cómo extraigo el texto entre dos brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

he estado intentando hacer una expresión regular en javascript para obtener el texto entre medio de 2 brackets por ejemplo

```
[descripcion] Esta es una descripcion [/descripcion]
```

La cual me debería devolver " Esta es una descripción "

He estado probando con esta `(\Q[descripcion]\E)(\X*)(\Q[/descripcion]\E)`

Pero nada de nada, alguien me puede ayudar con la expresión ?

Otra cosa, el texto completo sin filtrar es asi

```
[descripcion] La Descripcion [/descripcion][ingredientes] Los ingredientes [/ingredientes][sabor] Sabor [/sabor][aroma] Aroma [/aroma][tiempo]3-5 min[/tiempo][temperatura]80°[/temperatura][cantidad]2,5g/250ml[/cantidad][preparacion] Preparacion [/preparacion][pais]China[/pais][contenido][/contenido][modouso][/modouso]
```

Yo solo quiero lo que esta dentro de `[descripcion] esto [/descripcion]`

Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Alguna necesidad particular de porque tiene que ser una regexp?

Comment: Personalmente creo que seria la forma mas correcta, que otro método conoces ?

Comment: un substring de lo que necesitas ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes definir una expresión como esta:

```
var reg = /\[descripcion\](.*)\[\/descripcion\]/
```

Las barras son para escapar los corchetes ya que son caracteres reservados y los paréntesis sirven para crear grupos. En este caso creamos un grupo con todo lo que esté escrito entre [descripcion][/descripción].

Para obtener el contenido de los grupos utilizamos exec, con lo que obtendrás un array con los grupos encontrados. En la posición 0 del array estará el texto que has pasado como parámetro, en la posición 1 el grupo 1, en la posición 2 el grupo 2, etc.

```
var grupos = reg.exec("[descripcion]Esta es una descripcion[/descripcion]");

console.log(grupos[0]); // [descripcion]Esta es una descripcion[/descripcion]
console.log(grupos[1]); // Esta es una descripcion
```

Comment: Wow, funciona perfecto, muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
texto = "[descripcion] Esta es una descripcion [/descripcion]";
// expresion regular
expresion=/^\[descripcion\](.*?)\[\/descripcion\]/;
  // usamos la funcion match para buscar la expresion
  // dentro del texto que se le pase y obtenemos la poscion 1
  // donde
  // 0. es la concidencia completa 
  // 1. el texto que necesitamos
  
resultado = texto.match(expresion)[1]

console.log(resultado);
```